# the result seems wrong

Tags: java

my code will be display me That is not an acceptable input. if I insert negative number. then proceed to prompt the input. But it continue to calculate. this is part of my code contains something wrong. but i did not see.

```
public static boolean checkOctal()
{
    boolean b = true;
    if (oct < 0 && oct > 99999999 )
    {
        b = false;
        System.out.println("That is not an acceptable input.");
    }
    int tmp;
    int tmp1 = oct;
    while (tmp1 > 0)
    {
        tmp = tmp1 % 10;
        tmp1 = tmp1 / 10;
        if (tmp >= 0 && tmp < 8)
        {
            continue;
        } else
        {
            b = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return b;

}
```

Comment: Wow, you really need to learn how to write more readable code. Where does *oct* come from?

Comment: sorry, this is only part of the wrong result and now it is solved

Answer (score 6):

you should write

`if (oct < 0 || oct > 99999999 )`

instead of

`if (oct < 0 && oct > 99999999 )`

`||` stands for or, while `&&` for and.

Comment: if you can find a number that's smaller than 0 and greater than 99999999 in the same time, you just might reinvent math :) Kidding. The problem is where onemach said, but it would be a good practice to put some extra brackets like:
      if ((oct < 0) && (oct > 99999999 ))

Comment: @QuadroQ: I disagree - while extra brackets can be useful *sometimes*, they can also be distracting - and in this case I'd definitely consider them more harmful than helpful.

Comment: It's not and agree/disagree situation. It's a coding convention recommended by Oracle. You can take a look here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-137265.html#554 (section 10.1)

Comment: This still isn't the full solution if the number is higher then 99999999, it will still calculate. Still an else missing for it to stop the while loop.

Comment: @RafaelCelerier yes, let Bolor Ch finish~

Answer (score 5):

Actually, I doubt that it's displaying anything. Look at the condition:

```
if (oct < 0 && oct > 99999999 )
```

How can a number be negative *and* largely positive at the same time? You want an "or" condition.

Next, look at what you're doing if you *did* meet the condition:

```
{
    b = false;
    System.out.println("That is not an acceptable input.");
}
```

You're just keeping going - it will return the right result (false) but it's pointless. You know the result already, so why not just return it?

You want:

```
if (oct < 0 || oct > 99999999 )
{
    System.out.println("That is not an acceptable input.");
    return false;
}
```

Or, better yet, perform the *validation* earlier (before calling the method) - and throw an exception if the input is invalid. Currently you're giving the same result for "invalid input" as for "valid but non-octal input" which doesn't sound like a good idea to me.

Note that the approach of "return as soon as you know the value" is one I'd take for the rest of the method too - I wouldn't bother with a `b` variable at all. I'd change your loop to something like this:

```
int value = oct;
while (value > 0)
{
    int digit = value % 10;
    if (digit >= 8)
    {
        return false;
    }
    value = value / 10;
}
return true;
```

You don't need to worry about `digit` being negative, as you've already checked that you started off with a non-negative value.

Additionally, it seems odd that this method doesn't have `oct` as a parameter. That would make it more self-contained.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably check your boolean logic:

```
if (oct < 0 && oct > 99999999 )
```

will never be true - no number is less than zero **and** larger than 999999 at the same time... The symbol `||` (logical "or") is what you need instead.

Cheers,